# Insert data into 3 related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to insert data into 3 related tables (SQL Server)

For example, I have tables Customer <-- Customer_Address --> Address 
After I insert data into Customer and Address, how do I insert the IDs from Customer and Address in to Customer_Address? (join table)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), @@IDENTITY can return a value from any scope:

```
DECLARE @CustomerId INT
DECLARE @AddressId INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

  INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (blah, blah) values (blah, blah)
  SET @CustomerId = SCOPE_IDENTITY

  INSERT INTO ADDRESS (blah, blah) values (blah, blah)
  SET @AddressId = SCOPE_IDENTITY 

  INSERT INTO CUSTOMERADDRESS (CustomerId,AddressId) values (@CustomerId,@AddressId)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert more than one row you can use the output clause:

```
declare @insertedAddresses table (OriginalID int, AddressID int);
declare @insertedCustomers table (OriginalID int, CustomerID int);

insert into dbo.Addresses (AddressData)
output source.OriginalID, inserted.AddressID into @insertedAddresses
select AddressData from source;

insert into dbo.Customers (CustomerData)
output source.OriginalID, inserted.CustomerID into @insertedCustomers
select CustomerData from source;

insert into dbo.Customer_Address (AddressID, CustomerID)
select a.AddressID, c.CustomerID
from @insertedAddresses a inner join @insertedCustomers c on c.OriginalID=a.OriginalID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the IDs from the Customer and Address tables are Identity columns, you can store the new ID into a variable.

```
DECLARE @CustomerID int

SELECT @CustomerID = @@IDENTITY FROM TABLE CUSTOMER
```

Similar syntax could be used for the Address table. Then in your `INSERT` statement you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Address (CustomerID, AddressID)
VALUES (@CustomerID, @AddressID)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a transaction, and remember the identities.  in sql server -

```
declare @CustomerId int
declare @AddressId int

begin tran
    insert into Customer (blah, blah) values (blah, blah)
    set @CustomerId = @@IDENTITY    --assuming there are no triggers
    insert into [Address] (blah, blah) values (blah, blah)
    set @AddressId = @@IDENTITY     --once again, no triggers to mess up the @@IDENTITY
    insert into CustomerAddress(CustomerId,AddressId) values (@CustomerId,@AddressId)
commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
Declare CustomerID int, AddressID int
```

insert into Customer (list, of, fields) values (list, of, values)
select @CustomerID=scope_Identity()
insert into Address (list, of, fields) values (list, of, values)
select @AddressID =scope_Identity()

insert into Customer_Address (CustomerID, AddressID) values (@CustomerID, @AddressID)

Answer (score 0):

If it is for an application, why don't just use Linq, you can accomplish things like this in just a few minutes, in a more compressive way and more thigh to the business logic model.

If not the I highly recommend the transaction and SCOPE_IDENTITY version, because if you are in a heavy loaded system, an other operation can do an insert and change the identity value so you will end with inconsistent data.